# How to insert into table 1 if not exists in table2?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to mysql. I have a problem in inserting record to table1 if it does not exist in table2.I have 2 tables table1 and table2 in the form:

```
table1

dep_id  start     stop     modified deleted                 
1       23456789  167921525   Yes      No
2       34567812  345678145   Yes      No
3       32789054  327890546   No       No


table2

start     stop     modified deleted                 
23456789  167921525  No       No
34567823  345678145  No       No
32789053  727890546  No       No
```

I am trying to insert values into table1's start and stop field values only if it does not exist in table2's "start" and "stop" columns. If it exists the I need to throw an error.
These tables do not have a primary key foreign key relationship.
I apologize for not knowing correct syntax but I have to do something like this in mysql and PHP.

```
Replace Into into table1 set 'start'=> $start,'stop' => $stop
(select 'start','stop' from table2 where table1.start and table1.stop not in table2.start and table2.stop);
```

How do I query these 2 tables to check if Table1.start and Table1.stop fields do not match with Table2.start and Table2.stop before inserting to table1?

Comment: I've just set up a SQLFiddle demo for my solution. Try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (start, stop)
SELECT    a.*
FROM      (SELECT 123456789 start, 234567890 stop) a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON (a.start,a.stop) IN ((b.start,b.stop))
WHERE     b.start IS NULL
```

Where `123456789` and `234567890` are your input values for `start` and `stop` respectively.

Then you can check it with rowCount or num_rows_affected based on what DB interface you're using (PDO, mysqli, etc.). If it's 0, then no record was inserted, otherwise, the insert occurred.

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5df5d/1)

Comment: Is there a way to parametrize the hard coded values 123456789 and 234567890

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.  This takes two values, $start and $stop, and only does the insert if it does not exist in table2:

```
insert into table1 (start, stop)
    select *
    from (select $start as start, $stop as stop) t
    where not exists (select 1 from table2 where start = $start and stop = $end)
```

Comment: I get a mysql error near ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from (select 168132540 as start, 168132540 as stop) w' at line 1  .My mysql version is mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.56, for pc-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: @user1028428 . . . I think you are missing the alias "t" at the end of the from line.

Comment: I added but still gave me error. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from (select 168132540 as start, 168132540 as stop)t '

Comment: @user1028428 . . . Does the select work by itself?  I don't have mysql where I am now and SQL Fiddle is not working, due to some security configuration here.

Comment: select *
    from (select $start as start, $stop as stop) t are we trying to select from table 1?

Comment: No.  That is just selecting the constants that you want to insert.  In order to use the WHERE clause, there has to be something in the FROM clause.

Comment: Oh!ok.. I tried without where clause but no luck...            INSERT INTO table1 (account_id,start,stop,comment,deleted) values ('rt5617362',168132540,168132540,'some machine',0) select * from (select 168132540 as start, 168132540 as stop)t;                                                                                                            
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from (select 168132540 as start, 168132540 as stop) t' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

With parameterized values:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (start, stop)
SELECT    a.*
FROM      (SELECT ? start, ? stop) a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON (a.start,a.stop) IN ((b.start,b.stop))
WHERE     b.start IS NULL
```

This works but we do the `insert` through SQL statements.

Now, what would be the solution to insert the records by Interface? That is without SQL statement, with the restriction proposed in the problem.