# insert into table only if not exist on other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do the following thing: 
I have two tables: ReportImage (imageId, reportId, counter)
                   and userReportedImages (imageId, userId)

I want that every user will be able to report an image only once - this means that first I want to check if there is a row in 'userReportedImages' with the values (imageId, userId) if so do nothing, else create a row in 'ReportImage' with the values (imageId, reportId, counter), if such row already exist (other user reported that image) then I want to raise the counter.

so far before checking for same user report I had the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO ReportImage VALUES (imageId,reportId,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter+1
```

this statement is working fine.

I tried to change this statement to first check if the row exist on the other table, but I didn't manage to do it, can you help me?

Comment: You'd need a procedure/function for that.

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998585/how-to-insert-into-table-1-if-not-exists-in-table2?rq=1

Comment: why are you inserting on `ReportWrongLanguage`? isn't it `ReportImage`?

Comment: J W that was just a copy mistake - copied the wrong statement, but both do the same

Comment: have a unique index on the columns needed - any insert will result in an error which you can catch. An insert trigger will work as well. A third option is to do a select before insert and check if the user has inserted something already (imho not as good for performance reasons but works)

Comment: @DreamEater it isn't needed for a stored procedure on this, just an `INSERT INTO..SELECT` will do just fine.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to define a `UNIQUE` constraint or a compund column primary key on table `ReportImage`,

```
ALTER TABLE ReportImage ADD CONTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE(ImageID, ReportID)
```

Give this a try,

```
INSERT INTO ReportImage(ImageID, ReportID, Counter)
SELECT  'imageID HERE' AS ImageID,
        'userID HERE' AS ReportID,
        1 AS Counter
FROM    userReportedImages a
        LEFT JOIN ReportImage b
            ON  a.imageId = b.imageId AND
                a.userId = b.ReportID AND
                a.imageID = 'imageID HERE' AND
                a.userID = 'userID HERE'
WHERE   b.imageId IS NULL OR 
        b.ReportID IS NULL
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = VALUES(counter) + 1
```

Comment: tell if it throws ambiguous column exception.

Comment: it does, about the 'counter' column,
and the imageId, reportId, and counter columns are from the reportImage table and not from 'userReportedImages' table, tnx a lot

Comment: #1052 - Column 'counter' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: try executing this first `ReportImage.counter = ReportImage.counter + 1` or if it still fails, try this one `b.counter = b.counter + 1`

Comment: both giving me:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'b.counter = b.counter + 1 INSERT INTO ReportImage(ImageID, ReportID, Counter) ' at line 1

Comment: how about `ReportImage.counter = ReportImage.counter + 1`?

Comment: wait i think this one will work: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = VALUES(counter) + 1`

Comment: now it is giving me:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE b.imageId IS NULL OR b.ReportID IS NULL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPD' at line 8

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26815/discussion-between-j-w-and-shai-zarzewski)

Answer (score 1):

you could try using `NOT EXISTS`

```
insert into table2(`name`)
select * from (select 'name1' as name) tmp
where not exists(
  select ('x') from table1 where name = 'test1'
  );
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/474e5/1)

Answer (score 0):

An insert trigger should be a solution for you:  [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)