# Parametrized insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert values in table1 if it does not exist on table2. While I can do that using the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (start, stop)
SELECT    a.*
FROM      (SELECT 123456789 start, 234567890 stop) a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON (a.start,a.stop) IN ((b.start,b.stop))
WHERE     b.start IS NULL
```

You can see the example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11998641/719554

I would like to parametrize 123456789 and 234567890 using PDO. HOw can I accomplish that? I thought that I could simply do the following

```
INSERT INTO table1 (start, stop)
SELECT    a.*
FROM      (SELECT :start AS start, :stop AS stop) a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON (a.start,a.stop) IN ((b.start,b.stop))
WHERE     b.start IS NULL
```

Comment: Have you tried  yet? At least try it and then we'll help troubleshoot it if it's not working.

Comment: Why not use a stored procedure to do this?

Comment: Yes I have tried. I mean there is not much to try except changing two things or at least that's what I thought!

Comment: This is a really convoluted query. What's the objective here?

Comment: insert a record in table1 if it does not exist in table 2. The record is arbitrary!

Comment: Is there a better way of doing it?